# Internal Server Error in B2C for Email/UPN in Username Field

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

When I try to create a local account w/ a username of "test@mydomain.com" I get:

> http://localhost:4343/#error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C90161:+A+self-asserted+send+response+has+failed+with+reason+'Internal+Server+Error'.
>   Correlation+ID:+cb299c64-219b-4870-9b4e-7c85fbbd2ae3
>   Timestamp:+2018-02-20+21:05:54Z
>   &state=9ac8534f-ad75-46c1-94a8-514a71acc6bb

I've wired up [App Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-troubleshoot-custom) and I can see the "Internal Servier Error" but there is so much noise I can't pinpoint the problem.

---

1. Why can't I register w/ a username like that?
2. How do I interrupt the app insight log to track down my issue?

---

Note: I'm using custom policies if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for the first question is that a sign-in name of **type** "userName" can't contain the '@' character in the **value** property.

i.e. You can't set it to an email address.